# NStimer issue in Cocoa-Touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsobject, nstimeinterval

My application needs to show a temporary message, so I created Toast like android myself. It works well for only one toast. I am using NSTimer to hide the message. If I display more than one toast the timer becomes a problem. Only the last added toast becomes hidden, others do not become hidden. How can I hide all toasts?

Code:

Remove function:

```
-(void)removeToast
{
 NSLog(@"removed");
 [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Timer start:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(4.0f) 
                                         target:self  
                                       selector:@selector(xxxx)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

I wrote this in above in separate `NSObject` class and created an object. I need some clarification on how run the two NSTimer simultaneously or keep track of all `NSObjects`.

Object creation in viewcontroller is
 `@property(nonatomic,strong)Toast *toast;`

Comment: If I understand you right you need to keep two NSTimer around? If so I would create two instance variables which holds the timers.

Comment: why don't you use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:?

Answer (score 1):

No need to keep the istance of timer in a ivar for your purpose. Use the userinfo: parameter to pass the view you mean to hide when the timer fires, like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(4.0f) 
                                     target:self  
                                   selector:@selector(xxxx)
                                   userInfo:yourView repeats:NO];
```

Then in your selector retrieve the view from the userInfo and hide it. You can find a working sample [here](https://github.com/andreamazz/UIView-Notify/blob/master/UIView+Notify/UIView+Notify.m), line 37.